# Rearrange data into specified row lengths

Tags: macos, bash, syntax, awk

*Note: I'm using OS X*

I have a data file that is just a long list of numbers, with each entry on a separate line:

```
    23
    28
    26
    14
    ...
```

I need to rearrange the data in rows 37 records/fields long:

```
23 28 26 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 4 5 6 9 4 8 7 6 3 2 5 9 4 1 2 5 7 8 9 4 6 1 2
 5 8 6 4 3 5 23 28 26 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 4 5 6 9 4 8 7 6 3 2 5 9 4 1 2 5 7 
 ...
```

This is the code I've tried:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1) { 
        if(i%37 != 0) printf $i" "; 
        else printf "$i\n" 
        }
     }' 
    input.txt > output.txt
```

The first `printf $i" "` seems to be working, but somethings seems to be wrong with the conditional because no matter what I tell it to print in the `else` statement it doesn't print it. Perhaps just a syntax oversight??

Interestingly, when I just run:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1) printf $i" "}' input.txt > output.txt
```

the resultant file puts *some* of the data into 37-record-length rows, but some are still much longer...could this be a result of some artifact in the data? (The data has been run through a number of sorting/organizing functions.)

Comment: The crux of your problem is that you used the term "records/fields". They are NOT the same and you are confused about the difference. A file is made up of records. Each record is made up of fields. The default record separator is a newline. The default field separator is a sequence of contiguous white space. So, your input file contains 37 records and each record contains 1 field. Your script is comparing `NF` (the number of fields in the current record) against 37. See the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NF` variable is the number of fields within a record. You should use the `NR` variable, that represents the record number:

```
awk '{printf NR%37?"%d ":"%d\n", $1}' file
```

Comment: that worked perfectly; thanks! still don't quite understand why my original loop didn't work...and I'll have to read some more to understand exactly what your one-line `awk` is doing...but thanks!

Comment: @zephyr44 It uses the ternary operator `... ? ... : ... `. If the value before the `?` is true (non-zero), then the value between the `?` and `:` is used. If it is false (zero) the value after the `:` is used. In this case, if the record number `NR` is not a multiple of 37, then the format string that is used is `"%d "`. Otherwise, if it is a multiple, then the format string is `"%s\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that might be helpful for you `xargs -n37 < file`.

**Demo**

The command `seq` just print a seqence of number that are seperated by a newline *(default)* using `xargs -n3` we can group the single column into records with 3 fields:

```
$ seq 1 9 | xargs -n3 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```